# How do I get unique struct values from an array of structs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, struct, unique

I am fairly new to Ruby and was wondering if there is a way to extract unique struct values within an array.

I have the following struct:

```
Struct.new(:source_ip_address, :destination_ip_address, :port)
```

Within my code I am getting these struct values from a file, then storing them in an array:

```
ip_port_list
```

So basically for each line in the file, a new struct is created. That struct is then added to the `ip_port_list` array. The next thing I am trying to do is pull out all the unique `port` values within the entire array. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ip_port_list.map(&:port).uniq
```

Should do it.